# Randomly Rearrange items in a LazyRow - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a LazyRow. Everything works fine. I just want the items to be randomly rearranged every time this LazyRow is drawn on the screen. Here is my code:

```
LazyRow(
        reverseLayout = true,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = twelveDp, end = eightDp)
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(
            items = featureUsersLazyPagingItems,
            key = { _, featuredPerson ->
                featuredPerson.uid
            }
        ) { _, featuredUser ->
            featuredUser?.let {
                //Daw the age suggested People
                DrawSuggestedPerson(featuredUser.toPersonUser(),) {
                    homeViewModel.deleteFeaturedUserFromLocalDb(featuredUser.uid)
                }
            }
        }

        featureUsersLazyPagingItems.apply {
            when {
                loadState.refresh is LoadState.Loading -> {
                    item {
                        ShowLazyColumnIsLoadingProgressBar()
                    }
                }
                loadState.append is LoadState.Loading -> {
                    item {
                        ShowLazyColumnIsLoadingProgressBar()
                    }
                }
                loadState.refresh is LoadState.Error -> {
                    val e = featureUsersLazyPagingItems.loadState.refresh as LoadState.Error
                    item {
                        LazyColumnErrorView(
                            message = e.error.localizedMessage!!,
                            onClickRetry = { retry() }
                        )
                    }
                }
                loadState.append is LoadState.Error -> {
                    val e = featureUsersLazyPagingItems.loadState.append as 
LoadState.Error
                    item {
                        LazyColumnErrorView(
                            message = e.error.localizedMessage!!,
                            onClickRetry = { retry() }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

So the LazyRow displays the same set of 30 or so items but only 3- 4 items are visible on screen, for a bit of variety, I would like the items to be re-arranged so that the user can see different items on the screen. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: "every time the user navigates to the composable that emits this LazyRow" - can you add more details what do you mean by this? What's the initial action? `LazyRow` view appearing/disappearing? What navigation are you talking about?

Comment: I have updated the question, everytime the lAzyRow is drawn on the screen, I want the list of items that it displays to be rearranged

Comment: It can be redrawn when some state variable changes, if you use animations this can happen on each frame, so I guess that's not what you want. From the user perspective what should happen? User go to another screen and comes back?

Comment: What if you shuffle your array list as soon as you set that in the lazyRow ?

Comment: @PhilipDukhov This LazyRow is on my HomeActivity so this should happen everytime user opens the app

Comment: @MohammedHanif. I am passing a variable of the lazyingPagingItems to the LazyRow, so would we shuffle it before passing it as a variable

Comment: @AnudeepAnanth is that variable an array or list ?

Comment: @MohammedHanif.The variable "featureUsersLazyPagingItems" that I am passing to the lazyRow is of the type LaxyPagingItems<MyCustomClass>

Answer (score 1):

You can shuffle your list inside `remember`, by doing this you're sure that during one view appearance your order will be the same, and it'll be shuffled on the next view appearance. I'm passing `featureUsersLazyPagingItems` as a key, so if `featureUsersLazyPagingItems` changes `shuffledItems` will be recalculated.

```
val shuffledItems = remember(featureUsersLazyPagingItems) {
    featureUsersLazyPagingItems.shuffled()
}
```

The only problem of `remember` is that it'll be reset on screen rotation. Not sure if you need that, and if you wanna save state after rotation, you need to use `rememberSaveable`. As it can only store simple types, which your class isn't, you can store indices instead, like this:

```
val shuffledItemIndices = rememberSaveable(featureUsersLazyPagingItems) {
    featureUsersLazyPagingItems.indices.shuffled()
}
val shuffledItems = remember(featureUsersLazyPagingItems, shuffledItemIndices) {
    featureUsersLazyPagingItems.indices
        .map(featureUsersLazyPagingItems::get)
}
```

I suggest you checkout out [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state) for details of how state works in compose.